How to get remote current directory using Apache sshd SftpClient API?
I can see JSCH has feature to get current directory using ChannelSftp.pwd();
How it can be achieved using Apache Mina sshd library ? I want to find the landing directory on successful SFTP connection ?
I dont find the similar pwd() API for SftpClient.

SftpClient.canonicalPath(".")

@AndreyB.Panfilov Thanks for suggestion, it helped to get current directory.
